# Помогите посчитать количество совпадений в бд

Tags: sql, yii2, postgresql, activerecord

Вопрос такой: я ищу в бд postgres по полю name, например строка поиска:test new test1 new1
в бд есть записи:

```
1. test1 new new2
2. test2 new test3
3. test3 new3 test3
```

Видно, что первая запись совпадает по 2 словам, вторая по 1, 3 не будет в выборке, т.е. у меня результирующих 2 записи.
Как мне отсортировать их по этим совпадениям?

Запрос я написал, но он не правильно работает

```
SELECT *, RANK() OVER(ORDER BY id) AS "rnk"
  FROM "product"
 WHERE ("category_id"=16) AND ("id" != 1175) AND ("distributor_id" != 7)
   AND ( ("name" ILIKE '%SolarWorld%') OR ("name" ILIKE '%295W%')
       OR ("name" ILIKE '%Plus%') OR ("name" ILIKE '%295%')
       OR ("name" ILIKE '%mono%') OR ("name" ILIKE '%5BB%')
   )
 ORDER BY "rnk" DESC LIMIT 9
```

Comment: Количество можно получить как `("name" ILIKE '%SolarWorld%')::int + ("name" ILIKE '%295W%')::int +...`

Comment: а куда это можно вставить? в having? извиняюсь сразу за тупой вопрос, не шарю пока

Comment: В order by например, или если надо видеть само значение - вверх запроса, вместо rank